# Lower and upper limit for time in Ionic2

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to make a form where user need to book a time slot between 8:00 AM to 4:00 PM. All the time slots should be in 30 mins slot.

For example - 8:00 AM, 8:30 AM, 9:00 AM, 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM, 10:30 AM, 11:00 AM, 11:30 AM, 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM, 1:00 PM, 1:30 PM, 2:00 PM, 2:30 PM, 3:00 PM, 3:30 PM,4:00 PM.

I need to make sure that user select time between 8:00 AM to 4:00 PM.
How can i achieve this by using ionic2 date time.

This is what i tried but its not working-

```
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A"  hourValues='8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16' minuteValues="0,30" pickerFormat="h mm A" [(ngModel)]="event.timeStarts"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've try with DateTime component but i think you could do this `pickerFormat="H mm"`. this's not consistent with display format but you could avoid user pick a wrong time, for example 1:30AM as `pickerFormat="h mm A"` does.